# Launch Processes Automatically When Opening Workspace in VSCode

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

When I open a workspace in VSCode, the first thing I do is to run a open multiple terminals and run a series of NPM scripts to handle ongoing processes:

1. Babel build
2. Tests
3. Run site / app

Is there any way to automate this process, so that when I open a workspace, the terminals are opened and the scripts executed.

I used [Tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) in the past, but is there a way to do this within VSCode?